# Конфликт при установке Laravel версии dev-develop (composer)

Tags: laravel, composer

При установке Laravel возникают конфликты. Composer последний на данный момент. Такой проблемы в инете не нашел.

```
$ сomposer create-project laravel/laravel learning-laravel-5 dev-develop



Installing laravel/laravel (dev-develop 53b59cd0ba6c9e99a9559b121ca390e023feab55)
  - Installing laravel/laravel (dev-develop 53b59cd): Cloning 53b59cd0ba from cache
Created project in learning-laravel-5
> @php -r "file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');"
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - beyondcode/laravel-dump-server 1.0.0 requires illuminate/http 5.6.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/http[5.6.x-dev, v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12, v5.6.13, v5.6.14, v5.6.15, v5.6.16, v5.6.17, v5.6.19, v5.6.2, v5.6.20, v5.6.21, v5.6.22, v5.6.23, v5.6.24, v5.6.25, v5.6.26, v5.6.27, v5.6.28, v5.6.29, v5.6.3, v5.6.30, v5.6.31, v5.6.32, v5.6.33, v5.6.34, v5.6.35, v5.6.36, v5.6.37, v5.6.38, v5.6.39, v5.6.4, v5.6.5, v5.6.6, v5.6.7, v5.6.8, v5.6.9].
    - beyondcode/laravel-dump-server 1.1.0 requires illuminate/http 5.6.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/http[5.6.x-dev, v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12, v5.6.13, v5.6.14, v5.6.15, v5.6.16, v5.6.17, v5.6.19, v5.6.2, v5.6.20, v5.6.21, v5.6.22, v5.6.23, v5.6.24, v5.6.25, v5.6.26, v5.6.27, v5.6.28, v5.6.29, v5.6.3, v5.6.30, v5.6.31, v5.6.32, v5.6.33, v5.6.34, v5.6.35, v5.6.36, v5.6.37, v5.6.38, v5.6.39, v5.6.4, v5.6.5, v5.6.6, v5.6.7, v5.6.8, v5.6.9].
    - beyondcode/laravel-dump-server 1.1.1 requires illuminate/http 5.6.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/http[5.6.x-dev, v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12, v5.6.13, v5.6.14, v5.6.15, v5.6.16, v5.6.17, v5.6.19, v5.6.2, v5.6.20, v5.6.21, v5.6.22, v5.6.23, v5.6.24, v5.6.25, v5.6.26, v5.6.27, v5.6.28, v5.6.29, v5.6.3, v5.6.30, v5.6.31, v5.6.32, v5.6.33, v5.6.34, v5.6.35, v5.6.36, v5.6.37, v5.6.38, v5.6.39, v5.6.4, v5.6.5, v5.6.6, v5.6.7, v5.6.8, v5.6.9].
    - beyondcode/laravel-dump-server 1.1.2 requires illuminate/http 5.6.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/http[5.6.x-dev, v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12, v5.6.13, v5.6.14, v5.6.15, v5.6.16, v5.6.17, v5.6.19, v5.6.2, v5.6.20, v5.6.21, v5.6.22, v5.6.23, v5.6.24, v5.6.25, v5.6.26, v5.6.27, v5.6.28, v5.6.29, v5.6.3, v5.6.30, v5.6.31, v5.6.32, v5.6.33, v5.6.34, v5.6.35, v5.6.36, v5.6.37, v5.6.38, v5.6.39, v5.6.4, v5.6.5, v5.6.6, v5.6.7, v5.6.8, v5.6.9].
    - beyondcode/laravel-dump-server 1.1.3 requires illuminate/http 5.6.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/http[5.6.x-dev, v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12, v5.6.13, v5.6.14, v5.6.15, v5.6.16, v5.6.17, v5.6.19, v5.6.2, v5.6.20, v5.6.21, v5.6.22, v5.6.23, v5.6.24, v5.6.25, v5.6.26, v5.6.27, v5.6.28, v5.6.29, v5.6.3, v5.6.30, v5.6.31, v5.6.32, v5.6.33, v5.6.34, v5.6.35, v5.6.36, v5.6.37, v5.6.38, v5.6.39, v5.6.4, v5.6.5, v5.6.6, v5.6.7, v5.6.8, v5.6.9].
    - beyondcode/laravel-dump-server 1.2.0 requires illuminate/http 5.6.*|5.7.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/http[5.6.x-dev, 5.7.17, 5.7.18, 5.7.19, 5.7.x-dev, v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12, v5.6.13, v5.6.14, v5.6.15, v5.6.16, v5.6.17, v5.6.19, v5.6.2, v5.6.20, v5.6.21, v5.6.22, v5.6.23, v5.6.24, v5.6.25, v5.6.26, v5.6.27, v5.6.28, v5.6.29, v5.6.3, v5.6.30, v5.6.31, v5.6.32, v5.6.33, v5.6.34, v5.6.35, v5.6.36, v5.6.37, v5.6.38, v5.6.39, v5.6.4, v5.6.5, v5.6.6, v5.6.7, v5.6.8, v5.6.9, v5.7.0, v5.7.1, v5.7.10, v5.7.11, v5.7.15, v5.7.2, v5.7.20, v5.7.21, v5.7.22, v5.7.23, v5.7.26, v5.7.27, v5.7.28, v5.7.3, v5.7.4, v5.7.5, v5.7.6, v5.7.7, v5.7.8, v5.7.9].
    - beyondcode/laravel-dump-server 1.2.1 requires illuminate/http 5.6.*|5.7.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/http[5.6.x-dev, 5.7.17, 5.7.18, 5.7.19, 5.7.x-dev, v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12, v5.6.13, v5.6.14, v5.6.15, v5.6.16, v5.6.17, v5.6.19, v5.6.2, v5.6.20, v5.6.21, v5.6.22, v5.6.23, v5.6.24, v5.6.25, v5.6.26, v5.6.27, v5.6.28, v5.6.29, v5.6.3, v5.6.30, v5.6.31, v5.6.32, v5.6.33, v5.6.34, v5.6.35, v5.6.36, v5.6.37, v5.6.38, v5.6.39, v5.6.4, v5.6.5, v5.6.6, v5.6.7, v5.6.8, v5.6.9, v5.7.0, v5.7.1, v5.7.10, v5.7.11, v5.7.15, v5.7.2, v5.7.20, v5.7.21, v5.7.22, v5.7.23, v5.7.26, v5.7.27, v5.7.28, v5.7.3, v5.7.4, v5.7.5, v5.7.6, v5.7.7, v5.7.8, v5.7.9].
    - beyondcode/laravel-dump-server 1.2.2 requires illuminate/http 5.6.*|5.7.*|5.8.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/http[5.6.x-dev, 5.7.17, 5.7.18, 5.7.19, 5.7.x-dev, 5.8.x-dev, v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12, v5.6.13, v5.6.14, v5.6.15, v5.6.16, v5.6.17, v5.6.19, v5.6.2, v5.6.20, v5.6.21, v5.6.22, v5.6.23, v5.6.24, v5.6.25, v5.6.26, v5.6.27, v5.6.28, v5.6.29, v5.6.3, v5.6.30, v5.6.31, v5.6.32, v5.6.33, v5.6.34, v5.6.35, v5.6.36, v5.6.37, v5.6.38, v5.6.39, v5.6.4, v5.6.5, v5.6.6, v5.6.7, v5.6.8, v5.6.9, v5.7.0, v5.7.1, v5.7.10, v5.7.11, v5.7.15, v5.7.2, v5.7.20, v5.7.21, v5.7.22, v5.7.23, v5.7.26, v5.7.27, v5.7.28, v5.7.3, v5.7.4, v5.7.5, v5.7.6, v5.7.7, v5.7.8, v5.7.9, v5.8.0, v5.8.2, v5.8.3].
    - don't install illuminate/http 5.6.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework 5.9.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.0|don't install laravel/framework 5.9.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.1|don't install laravel/framework 5.9.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.10|don't install laravel/framework 5.9.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.11|don't install laravel/framework 5.9.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.12|don't install laravel/framework 5.9.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.13|don't install laravel/framework 5.9.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.14|don't install laravel/framework 5.9.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.15|don't install laravel/framework 5.9.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.16|don't install laravel/framework 5.9.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.17|don't install laravel/framework 5.9.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.19|don't install laravel/framework 5.9.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.2|don't install laravel/framework 5.9.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.20|don't install laravel/framework 5.9.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.21|don't install laravel/framework 5.9.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.22|don't install laravel/framework 5.9.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.23|don't install laravel/framework 5.9.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.24|don't install laravel/framework 5.9.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.25|don't install laravel/framework 5.9.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.26|don't install laravel/framework 5.9.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.27|don't install laravel/framework 5.9.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.28|don't install laravel/framework 5.9.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.29|don't install laravel/framework 5.9.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.3|don't install laravel/framework 5.9.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.30|don't install laravel/framework 5.9.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.31|don't install laravel/framework 5.9.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.32|don't install laravel/framework 5.9.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.33|don't install laravel/framework 5.9.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.34|don't install laravel/framework 5.9.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.35|don't install laravel/framework 5.9.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.36|don't install laravel/framework 5.9.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.37|don't install laravel/framework 5.9.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.38|don't install laravel/framework 5.9.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.39|don't install laravel/framework 5.9.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.4|don't install laravel/framework 5.9.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.5|don't install laravel/framework 5.9.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.6|don't install laravel/framework 5.9.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.7|don't install laravel/framework 5.9.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.8|don't install laravel/framework 5.9.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.9|don't install laravel/framework 5.9.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/http 5.7.17|don't install laravel/framework 5.9.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/http 5.7.18|don't install laravel/framework 5.9.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/http 5.7.19|don't install laravel/framework 5.9.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/http 5.7.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework 5.9.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.7.0|don't install laravel/framework 5.9.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.7.1|don't install laravel/framework 5.9.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.7.10|don't install laravel/framework 5.9.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.7.11|don't install laravel/framework 5.9.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.7.15|don't install laravel/framework 5.9.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.7.2|don't install laravel/framework 5.9.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.7.20|don't install laravel/framework 5.9.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.7.21|don't install laravel/framework 5.9.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.7.22|don't install laravel/framework 5.9.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.7.23|don't install laravel/framework 5.9.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.7.26|don't install laravel/framework 5.9.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.7.27|don't install laravel/framework 5.9.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.7.28|don't install laravel/framework 5.9.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.7.3|don't install laravel/framework 5.9.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.7.4|don't install laravel/framework 5.9.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.7.5|don't install laravel/framework 5.9.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.7.6|don't install laravel/framework 5.9.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.7.7|don't install laravel/framework 5.9.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.7.8|don't install laravel/framework 5.9.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.7.9|don't install laravel/framework 5.9.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/http 5.8.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework 5.9.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.8.0|don't install laravel/framework 5.9.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.8.2|don't install laravel/framework 5.9.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.8.3|don't install laravel/framework 5.9.x-dev
    - Installation request for laravel/framework 5.9.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[5.9.x-dev].
    - Installation request for beyondcode/laravel-dump-server ^1.0 -> satisfiable by beyondcode/laravel-dump-server[1.0.0, 1.1.0, 1.1.1, 1.1.2, 1.1.3, 1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.2.2].
```

Answer (score 1):

Проблема воспроизводится у меня тоже. У пакетов `"laravel/framework": "5.9.*"` и `"beyondcode/laravel-dump-server": "^1.0"` конфликт по требованиям, которые они предъявляют к зависимости - пакету `illuminate/http`.

`laravel/laravel`, ветка *develop*, в конце февраля, у пакета-зависимости `laravel/framework` сменился минорный номер у версии. Если устанавливать laravel с помощью команды `сomposer create-project --prefer-source laravel/laravel learning-laravel-5 dev-develop`, то можно откатится к коммиту *75468420* (от 9 февраля 2019) и конфликт исчезнет.

Откатится:

```
git reset --hard 75468420
```

Установить зависимости:

```
composer install
```

В будущем, когда конфликт поправят и изменения появятся в мастер-репозитории - можно будет вытянуть последние правки:

```
git pull origin develop
composer update
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Ты прав, только я чуть по другому сделал. Теперь использую : 

        composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel dirName

Comment: @НовиковДенис, да так можно, но это для  установки версии из ветки *master*. В ней пакет-зависомость "старая" -  `laravel/framework": "5.8.*"` и такой проблемы не наблюдается. Я ответил как решить именно Вашу проблему для версии _develop_ - про нее ведь был вопрос. Команда `сomposer create-project laravel/laravel learning-laravel-5 dev-develop`  устанавливает версию из ветки *develop*.

Comment: А, вот как. Спасибо за разъяснение.

Answer (score 0):

если composer установлен правильно то напиши в cmd windows где у тебя установлен 
composer

```
composer global require laravel/installer.
```

Если не получается то вот документация 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8